# How could I refactor the waterfall method from async to use ES6 promises?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a route that allows a user to reset their password by sending them an email. Standard procedure for most websites. In this route, I import the async npm module and use the waterfall method so that I can handle the asynchronous nature of multiple functions. I'm still having a bit of trouble understanding promises, but I'm trying to replace waterfall with a promise or promise chain.

How could I refactor this route with a promise? Here are the steps contained in this route that is currently split up into 4 functions with waterfall.

1. First the route creates a reset token
2. Search for user based on email
   2.5. If user is found, save user, otherwise return 404
3. Send email to user containing a reset url
4. Return a status of 200.

   ```
   app.post('/forgotPassword', function(req, res, next) {

       waterfall([
           // generate reset token
           function(done) {
               crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
           var token = buf.toString('hex');
           done(err, token);
       });
           },
           function(token, done) {
               // search for user with the given email
               User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
                   // check to see if the user exists
                   if (!user) {
                       // user doesn't exist in database
                       return res.status(404).send();
                   }
                   // user exists, assign token with expiration date
                   user.resetPasswordToken = token;
                   user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour from now

                   // save the user model with the newly added
                   // token and expiration date
                   user.save(function(err) {
                       done(err, token, user);
                   });
               });
       },
           function(token, user, done) {
               var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
                 service: 'SendGrid',
                 auth: {
                   user: config.sendgridUser,
                   pass: config.sendgridPassword
                 }
               });

               var mailOptions = {
                 to: user.email,
                 from: 'email@school.edu',
                 subject: 'Password Reset',
                 text: `Hello etc etc`,

               smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
                   done(err, 'done');
               });
           }],
               function(err) {
                   // handle error
                   if (err) return next(err);
                   res.status(200).send();
               });
       }); // end POST route '/forgotPassword'
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Promise` is a very powerful tool. It can be hard to understand it at the beginning, but totally worth the effort! Please let me know if you have any doubts :)

```
app.post('/forgotPassword', function(req, res, next) 
{
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    {
        // generate reset token
        crypto.randomBytes(20, (err, buf) =>
        {
            if(err)
                return reject(err);

            const token = buf.toString('hex');
            resolve(token);
        });     
    })
    .then((token) => 
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // search for user with the given email
            User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, user) => 
            {                       
                if (!user)
                    return reject(404);

                // user exists, assign token with expiration date
                user.resetPasswordToken = token;
                user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour from now

                // save the user model with the newly added
                // token and expiration date
                user.save(function(err) {
                    if(err)
                        return reject(err);

                    resolve(user);
                });
            });                 
        });
    })
    .then((user) => 
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
        {
            const smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', 
            {
              service: 'SendGrid',
              auth: {
                user: config.sendgridUser,
                pass: config.sendgridPassword
              }
            });

            const mailOptions = {
              to: user.email,
              from: 'email@school.edu',
              subject: 'Password Reset',
              text: `Hello etc etc`
            };

            smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (err) => 
            {
                if(err)
                    return reject(err);

                resolve();
            });             
        }); 
    })
    .then(() => res.sendStatus(200))        
    .catch((err) => 
    {
        //check if the error is the one from the DB where the user was not found
        if(err == 404) {
            return res.sendStatus(404);
        }

        return res.status(500).send(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: In the email's content, I must send along the token from the previous then block. How can I resolve the user and the token so that they can be used in the email section? I tried to just plug in token and user like this: resolve(user, token);    but that doesn't work. When I set them to an object, it does work. How would you recommend handling that?

Comment: I think that you could use the `resetPasswordToken` from the the `user` object (`user.resetPasswordToken`). 

However, to send more than one information to another Promise, you could build an object with the two variables and pass it to the `resolve` function - something like this: `resolve({ user, token })`. And then, in the other Promise, you could retrieve both information like this: `.then(({ user, token }) => { ... })`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for. The ES6 object destructuring is a nice touch!

Answer (score 1):

bluebird is one of the most popular promise library.
and it offers promisify function to convert callback hell to promise.

please read this document and play with it.

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/working-with-callbacks.html

Answer (score 1):

This answer presumes 4 completely sequential steps:

```
(Function () {

    Return Promise (function (resolve, promise) {

        // try to do some stuff

        if (success) {

            Resolve ("pass this value on to next link in the chain");
        }

        Reject();
    })()

    .then (function (value) {

        // do next step

        Return "pass this value on to next link in the chain";

    .then (function (value) {

        // do next step

        Return "pass this value on to next link in the chain";

    .catch (function (error) {

        // handle any reject or any error in the chain

        }
```

You could in relation to the individual `.then` also choose to return a `Promise`. Beware: any errors in the `.catch` block will be swallowed.

Comment: What do you mean by swallowed?

Comment: If there are any errors in the code in the catch block no error will be thrown and thereby not brought to your attention. So use extra efforts to avoid errors in that specific block

Comment: So you're saying there will be no error thrown if I return a promise in each then statement?

Comment: All rejects and all errors in the .then blocks will be passed on to the .catch block to be handled. But if the .catch block itself contains an error, no error will be thrown and thereby remain unnotified and unhandled for eternity - to put it in a dramatic way.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand what you mean. I appreciate the drama. Stackoverflow can be a tad plain for my taste!

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example with `ES6` promise but working code. You can refactor it further to have a clear reusable code. You can replace ES5 functions with ES6 arrow functions.

```
app.post('/forgotPassword', function(req, res, next) {

    var catch = function(err){
        return next(err);
    }:

    var error404 = function(){
        return res.status(404).send();
    };

    var success = function(){
        return res.status(200).send();
    };

    var step1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            } else {
                var token = buf.toString('hex');
                resolve(token);
            }
        });
    });

    var step2 = function(token) {
        // search for user with the given email
        User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
            // check to see if the user exists
            if (!user) {
                // user doesn't exist in database
                return {error404: true};
            }
            // user exists, assign token with expiration date
            user.resetPasswordToken = token;
            user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour from now

            // save the user model with the newly added
            // token and expiration date
            user.save(function(err) {
                return { error: err, token: token, user: user });
            });
        });
    };

    var step3 = function(obj) {
        if(obj.error){
            return catch(obj.error);
        } else if(obj.error404) {
            return error404();
        } else {
            var token = obj.token, user = obj.user;
            var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
                service: 'SendGrid',
                auth: {
                user: config.sendgridUser,
                pass: config.sendgridPassword
                }
            });

            var mailOptions = {
                to: user.email,
                from: 'email@school.edu',
                subject: 'Password Reset',
                text: `Hello etc etc`,

            smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
                if(err){
                    return catch(err);
                } else {
                    return success();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    step1.then(step2, catch).then(step3);

}); // end POST route '/forgotPassword'
```

Answer (score 0):

Promises work best when you're dealing with a library where methods already return them, or a library like bluebird that lets you promisify existing callback APIs, otherwise it's a lot of conversions.

If you're still set on refactoring with plain es6, put your promise-wrappers at the lowest possible level, for best effect and cleanest error handling, basically promisify manually:

```
let convert = (resolve, reject) => (err, res) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(res);

crypto.randomBytesAsync = n=>new Promise((y,n)=>crypto.randomBytes(n,convert(y,n)));
User.findOneAsync = u => new Promise((y, n) => User.findOne(u, convert(y, n)));
User.prototype.saveAsync = () => new Promise((y, n) => this.save(convert(y, n)));
```

Then use them like this:

```
app.post('/forgotPassword', function(req, res, next) {

  crypto.randomBytesAsync(20).then(buf => {
    var token = buf.toString('hex');
    // search for user with the given email
    return User.findOneAsync({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
      // check to see if the user exists
      if (!user) {
        // user doesn't exist in database
        res.status(404).send();
        throw;
      }
      // user exists, assign token with expiration date
      user.resetPasswordToken = token;
      user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour from now

      // save the user model with the newly added
      // token and expiration date
      return user.saveAsync().then(() => {
        var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
          service: 'SendGrid',
          auth: { user: config.sendgridUser, pass: config.sendgridPassword }
        });

        smtpTransport.sendMailAsync =
            o => new Promise((y, n) => smtpTransport.sendMail(o, convert(y, n)));

        return smtpTransport.sendMailAsync({
          to: user.email,
          from: 'email@school.edu',
          subject: 'Password Reset',
          text: `Hello etc etc`,
        });
      });
    })
  })
  .then(() => res.status(200).send())
  .catch(err => next(err));
}); // end POST route '/forgotPassword'
```